# A file system operation that would incur a seek/rotational cost

Tags: filesystems, ext4

I am looking to generate a workload that will do operations on a file system that will make the disk access to have rotational or seeking cost.

Env details:

partition size: 30 G.
File system : ext4.

I am basically looking to design a bad file access workload (i.e., the perf should be bad).

This is what I have tried so far:

Created a file, say 'X' (size ~400 MB). This was created on block group 45 (Actually it was spanning across multiple groups). My partition has 241 block groups. I created one more file and by chance this was created in group number 100 (We will call this D1). I created one more file, again by chance, which was allocated to group 45 (We will call this file D2. I created the file before populating X with some huge text).

I tried to run a script which would copy data from X to D1 and D2. I was thinking that the perf of these 2 copies should be very disparate. But this is not the case unfortunately. I am not able to understand why this happens.

**How can I make the FS to behave bad in terms of perf?**

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, all these operations are being cached in RAM, so you aren't interacting with the disk at all. Reads are done from RAM, writes are cached in RAM and your commands complete before the write to the disk has actually happened.

To fix this, start each test with these commands:

```
sync
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

And end with this:

```
sync
```

`sync` will flush all writes to disk. The `echo` command will throw away the cache so later reads will read from the disk. This must be run as root.

To make your life easier, instead of creating files and trying to get them in the right place, why not just do your reads directly from the dev file for the disk, e.g. `/dev/sda`?